# How to set length for PropertyGrid items in c#?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

For example I have 2 items: Item1 is `string` and Item2 is `int`. How can I set max length for Item1 8 chars and for Item2 5 digits(in c#)?

Comment: How about by have the property set throw an exception?

Comment: I want just set numbers < 1000 for item2, How can i it ?(When type 4 chars, item2 don't allow for typing this(more than 3 digits))

Comment: PropertyGrid does not support that type of scenario, afaik

Answer (score 0):

To do that, simply use [StringLengthAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) and [IntegerValidatorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.integervalidatorattribute.aspx).

```
class TestCase
{
  [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "The TestString value cannot exceed 8 characters.")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Value Required")]
  property string TestString;

  [IntegerValidator(MaxValue = 99999)]
  property int TestInt;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any effect on how the property grid treats the property.